# Sony xperia mini android emulator

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device

I am looking for an emulator for Eclipse for the Sony Xperia mini or the Samsung Galaxy mini phones. I could not find anything on the Internet. Can someone tell me if there is an emulator (an AVD plugin) or how I can emulate one using a generic emulator (i.e, what resolution, density etc to specify)?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to emulate the Sony Ericsson Xperia mini is to download the EDK from Sony Ericssons website, http://developer.sonyericsson.com/edk.

There is included a skin for the small phones in that kit.